# how to create a simple pagination in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

I have a project on which i need to implement pagination. I tried searching various time but couldn't find any satisfactory result. That's why I'm posting my question here --

This is Controller file IndexController.php

This is my indexAction, in which I'm trying to implement pagination -

```
public function indexAction() {

     $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout');

     //pagination
     $page = $this->_request->getParam('page');
     if (empty($page)) { 
        $page = 1; 
     }
     $paginator = $this->_objCoupon->getOnePageOfOrderEntries($page);
     $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
     //pagination ends


     $coupons = $this->_objCoupon->getAllcoupon();
     $storage  = new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session();

     $dataUser = $storage->read();
     $id       = $dataUser->id;
     //$id       = $storage->id;
     $arrCoupon = array();

     if(count($coupons) > 0) {

        $i= 0;
        foreach($coupons as $couponArray) {

            $arrCoupon[$i]["pid"]   = $couponArray['id'];
            $arrCoupon[$i]["title"] = $couponArray['partner_name'];
            $arrCoupon[$i]["img"]   = $couponArray['companylogo'];
            $arrCoupon[$i]["value"] = $couponArray['coupon_value'];

            $i++;
        }
    }
    $this->view->arrCoupon = $arrCoupon;
    $this->view->selectedcheckbox = $this->selectCheckboxes;
    $this->view->id = $id;
    $this->view->asd = 'all';
}
```

This is model file CouponModel.php

And this is my model function

```
public function getOnePageOfOrderEntries($page=1) {

    //$paginator = $this->_coupon->getAllcoupon();


    $query = "SELECT * FROM rechargecoupon WHERE online_offer = 'N' ORDER BY id ASC";
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(
            new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($query)
    );
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(20);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    return $paginator;
}
```

And in view I'm just trying to print paginator variable value for now.

This is View file index.phtml

```
<?php if (count($this->paginator)): ?>
<?php print_r($this->paginator); die; ?>
```

When I'm executing this file, I'm getting "Class Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect not found error".

Comment: Can you show me your view? and what are the filenames of your controller and views called?

Comment: I expect the docs for `Zend_Paginator*` would resolve this. I presume their purpose is to add an `OFFSET` into this query? Also, please edit your question to explain _which_ class is not found.

Comment: @Daan--pls check the source again

Comment: @Pankaj `Zend_Paginator` is in my opinion harder to use than to write your own pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You should have these variables in your action:

- `$currentPage` = value obtained from URL, has to be >= 1
- `$itemsPerPage` = hard coded value, ideally taken from configuration
- `$itemsCount` = `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...`
- `$pagesCount` = `ceil($itemsCount / $itemsPerPage)`
- `$items` = `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT ($currentPage - 1) * $itemsPerPage, $itemsPerPage`, these are items to be displayed, for example articles

When you set these variables in your action, you should pass them to your view and generate pagination from them, that means:

- If pages count is larger than 1:

  - display pagination
  - generate pagination from 1 to `$pagesCount` = 1, 2, 3 ... 10
  - each generated pagination number should have associated URL to your action
- If pages count is 1:

  - do not display pagination

Comment: i am having in my paginator.php file a code like 'protected static $_adapterLoader = null;' should we have to make changes in this because i am getting an exception like

exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'Array' was not found in the registry'

Answer (score 0):

First of all.
Correct to use

```
$query = $this->select()
              ->from('rechargecoupon')
              ->where('online_offer = ?', 'N')
              ->order('id ASC')

$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($query));
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage('50');
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
```

This is in the model.

In view

```
<?php if ($this->paginator->getTotalItemCount() !== 0): ?>
// echo elements you need
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->paginationControl( $this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'pagination.phtml' ); ?>
```

pagination.phtml displays pagination. 
in pagination.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount > 1): ?>
    <div>
        <!-- Previous page  -->
        <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->previous)); ?>">
                <span>&lt; <?php echo 'previous'; ?></span>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="disabled">&lt; <?php echo 'previous'; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- Page links -->
        <?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
            <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $page)); ?>">
                    <span><?php echo $page; ?></span>
                </a>
            <?php else: ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php if(!in_array($this->pageCount, $this->pagesInRange)): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->pageCount)); ?>">
                <span><?php echo $this->pageCount; ?></span>
            </a>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->next)); ?>">
                <span><?php echo 'next'; ?> &gt;</span>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="disabled"><?php echo 'next'; ?> &gt;</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```